# Replacing 2 pole switch with 2 single pole switches to control a fan/light separately

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a switch (Double pole / One throw) that controls the ceiling fan and light in my master bathroom (B1). I'm considering to replace it with two single switches, so I don't need to turn the light on if I want just to use a fan, and vice versa - to use a light without fan.

Some notes:

- When I turn the lights ON, the fan is ON with a delay (approx 1 min). If I turn the lights OFF, the fan is OFF with a delay approx 5 min. That delay is not controlled by that switch (it can't do that by specs).
- The same fan is also used for the second bathroom (B2). It also has a switch that controls it. However it works differently (less control). If I turn the lights ON only in B2, fan is not activated. If I then turn the lights in B1, it's activated. Next, if I turn the lights OFF in B1 but leave the B2 lights ON, the fan is still working till B2 lights are OFF (+ 5 min delay). So basically B2 switch can run the fan only if it's already activated by B1.

The wiring diagram looks like below:

Cable 1 (two ends, black (C1_1) and red(C1_2))

Cable 2 (one red end C2)

Cable 3 (one red end C3)

The switch has 4 terminals (let me name it T1-T2-T3-T4).

Connections:

C1_1 --> T1

C1_2 --> T3

T3 --> T4

C2 --> T2

C3 --> T2

Questions:

1) Is it correct to assume that switch really controls fan/light and can be replaced with two single switches? Or I need to wire more cables?

2) Is it correct to assume that T3 & T4 are for LINE, and T1 & T2 are for LOAD?

3) What is the purpose of C3? Does it have any relations to B2?

Comment: It is not very clear if you have two bathrooms that each have their own fan of the same model ... or ... if both bathrooms are vented by the same fan unit.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, both bathrooms are vented by the same unit

Comment: Is there some sort of controller that goes with this fan?

Comment: T1-4 doesn't help us if we don't know *which one connects to which* when the switch is closed.  Also if the switch has any internal bonds, straps or tabs. I tried inferring it but it's too ambiguous.  Also I take it you are in North America and failing to mention a clump of white wires in the back of the box?  Please elucidate or post photo(s).

Comment: @Harper, the switch is CLIPSAL 30MD (AU), however the names of T1-T4 may not match the names in specs as it's not clear which one is what. It appears the battery in my meter is dead atm, so can't test it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, the fan definitelly has some sort of controller as it controls when to be stiwtched ON/OFF, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: The 30MD is easily found on the web, but nothing shows its pinout, not even the data sheet.  However, accidental find..  You might want to Google the Clipsal 31VETF and 2031VETF.  Its installation instructions describe how to use  a 2-pole switch as a remote, and the wiring diagram looks very familiar. ..

Comment: Also you are in Au/NZ so your /2 cable is red and black.  (Red hot).  I mention that for others' sake.

Comment: @Harper, there are 3 reds and 1 black, and two reds (C2/C3) are connected to each other. That's why I'm confused and not sure this switch is really used as 2 pole switch.